# How to redirect URL using .htaccess with dynamic parameter?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

```
https://example.com/product-info/A100001
```

to

```
https://example.com/product-info/index/index/id/A100001
```

using htaccess redirect rule

A100001 will be dynamic like

```
A100001
A100002
A100003
A100004
....
```

I am trying this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product-info/A100001
RewriteRule ^$ /routing/index/index/id/? [L,R=301]
```

[Source](https://linchpinseo.com/htaccess-rules/)

Also tried other example but not working in my scnario

Anyone who expert in htacees rules can help me in this.

Comment: There are literally thousands of existing answers here on SO demonstrating how to implement a `RewriteRule`. Also there are many tutorials out there on the internet explaining exactly that. And there is an excellent documentation. Why don't you start yourself and try to solve that task. _Then_ , when you fail, _then_ is the time to ask here including your own implementation attempt along with an explanation what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Yes I am trying at my end but rules are not working as expected, that's why I raising the issue here to get help.

Comment: Which is perfectly fine. But then, just as written above, please include your best own implementation attempt and tell us what exactly is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product-info/A100001
> RewriteRule ^$ /routing/index/index/id/? [L,R=301]
> ```

Your example URL contains a URL-path only, it does not contain a *query string*. The rule you've posted would redirect `/?product-info/A100001` to `/routing/index/index/id/`.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(product-info)/(A\d{6})$ /$1/index/index/id/$2 [R=302,L]
```

The above would redirect a request of the form `/product-info/A123456` to `/product-info/index/index/id/A123456`.

The `$1` backreference simply contains `product-info`, captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (saves repitition) and `$2` contains the dynamic part (an `A` followed by 6 digits).

This is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Always test first with a 302 to avoid potential caching issues.

The order of directives in your `.htaccess` file is important. This rule will likely need to go near the top of the file, before any existing rewrites.

---

**UPDATE:**

> redirection is working with your code, Can you please let me know the parameter pattern, I need the number from A452218 to A572217

Regex does not handle numeric ranges, only character ranges. If you specifically only want to match numbers in the stated range then you would need to do something (more complex) like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(product-info)/A(45221[89]|4522[2-9]\d|452[3-9]\d{2}|45[3-9]\d{3}|4[6-9]\d{4}|5[0-6]\d{4}|57[01]\d{3}|572[01]\d{2}|57220\d|57221[0-7])$ /$1/index/index/id/A$2 [R=302,L]
```

NB: The `$2` backreference now only contains the dynamic number, less the `A` prefix, which is now explicitly included in the *substitution* string.

Comment: Thanks, @MrWhite, redirection is working with your code, Can you please let me know the parameter pattern, I need the number from A452218 to A572217

Comment: @PurushotamSharma The existing regex `A\d{6}` will cover that number range. Or do you specifically need to limit this only to numbers in that range?

Comment: If any number not this of between A452218 to A572217, I want to show an Invalid Number message

Comment: @PurushotamSharma I've updated my answer to match only numbers in the stated range.